# What format can I use for the destination drive when backing up with rsync?

Tags: rsync

What format can I use to back up a destination drive using rsync with Linux -  ext4, ntfs , fat32?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to backup.

- If permissions need to be preserved you should use ext where ext4 should be preferred.
- If the files are personal and you do not need to care about permissions you could use a windows file system. FAT32 has limits in filesize so I would advice against it. NTFS should be preferred.

I myself would always use the same file system as what you use for the originals.